# Level shifting from 3.3 V to 1.8 V at 500 MHz

Tags: circuit-design, rf, bjt, level-shifting, high-speed

How can I translate a unidirectional signal from 3.3 V to 1.8 V with a bandwidth of 500 MHz?

The signal I am interested in is the output of a high speed comparator (TLV3601) and I have to measure the time over threshold with 10 nanoseconds precision (Zynq HP I/O bank).

I was thinking of using RF BJT or a chain of diodes, but I have no clue if that could work.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot directly modify (re-design) the high speed comparator? Of course, you've not specified what this has to drive, either. And perhaps the existing comparator, even if it were designed to output 1.8 V, wouldn't be able to support the load you have in mind. Anyway, lots of details are missing here and this isn't a "simple bright-line answer solves all needs" kind of thing. But [check here](https://www.ti.com/logic-voltage-translation/voltage-translators-level-shifters/overview.html) for example. My guess is that you need to provide lots more detail and this isn't easy.

Comment: Resistive attenuator?

Comment: Can you use an open-collector comparator and just use 1.8 V for the pull-up instead of 3.3 V?

Comment: How far away is the level shifter from the comparator's output, and the input of the next stage? Is impedance matching necessary? Too many details missing.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided details of the next stage, but as a starting point you could consider a simple resistive divider.

The datasheet suggest 10mA output, so 150R-180R would give you the correct DC levels.

Having said that, you will need to very carefully consider the capacitive loading, as 10mA is not going to be able to drive much load at the speeds you are seeking.